# How can I get Visual Studio to output some property values during a build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, vcpkg

I am setting up some custom properties (vcpkg triplets) in a solution-wide .props file, e.g:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VcpkgTriplet Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'">x86-windows-custom</VcpkgTriplet>
    <VcpkgTriplet Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'">x64-windows-custom</VcpkgTriplet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

During a build, I would like this property to be output. Or if it already is, I'd like to know where that would be in the logs?

Comment: Something like `<Message Text="vcpkg = $(VcpkgTriplet)" Importance="High" />` should do it when added under a target.